# PHP Array not being set correctly

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I'm trying to read a few RSS feed details from a XML file with the following code:

```
$this->feedFile = file_get_contents(__ROOT__ . '/assets/feedList.xml'); //Define this externally
$this->feedDetailsArray = array();
$this->feedXML = new SimpleXMLElement($this->feedFile);
echo "1. =========";
print_r($this->feedXML);
echo "1. =========";
foreach($this->feedXML->Feed as $feedItem) {
    echo "2. =========";
    echo "AJ:: feedName " . var_dump($feedItem->FeedName) . " feedURL " . var_dump($feedItem->FeedURL) . "\n";
    echo "2. =========";
    $feedDetails = array(
        "feedName" => $feedItem->FeedName,
        "feedURL" => $feedItem->FeedURL/*,
        'favIconURL' => $feedItem->FavIconURL
        );
    echo "3. =========";
    var_dump($feedDetails);
    echo "3. =========";
```

The print_r outputs the following:

```
1. =========SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Feed] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [FeedName] => Hacker News
                    [FeedURL] => http://news.ycombinator.com/rss
                    [FavIconURL] => http://ycombinator.com/favicon.ico
                    [Segment] => Startups
                )

    .
    .
    .
```

The first var_dump (`echo "feedName " . var_dump($feedItem->FeedName) . " feedURL " . var_dump($feedItem->FeedURL) . "\n";`) outputs:

```
2. =========class SimpleXMLElement#38 (1) {
    string(11) "Hacker News"
}
class SimpleXMLElement#38 (1) {
    string(31) "http://news.ycombinator.com/rss"
}
AJ:: feedName  feedURL 
2. =========
```

And the 2nd var_dump outputs:

```
3. =========array(2) {
  'feedName' =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#38 (1) {
        string(11) "Hacker News"
  }
  'feedURL' =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#37 (1) {
        string(31) "http://news.ycombinator.com/rss"
  }
}
3. =========
```

My question is, why does the statement `"feedName" => $feedItem->FeedName` result in the object being assigned instead of the value of the SimpleXML object? I only want the value and not the object. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleXML implements the [`__toString()` magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) on its objects, which are otherwise assigned by object reference. When they are used in context of an `echo`ed string (as one example), you'll get the string value returned, but on a normal assignment or reference you'll get the whole `SimpleXMLElement` object.

If you want the string value, you can cast it to a string:

```
$feedDetails = array(
    "feedName" => (string)$feedItem->FeedName,
    "feedURL" => (string)$feedItem->FeedURL
 );
```